# How to send message to only one filehandler from logger class

Tags: python-3.x, flask, logging

So I've setup a single logger with multiple handlers in my flask app. From the research I've done this far it seems you can only have one logger in a flask app. So to manage different streams I need to add handlers. My issue with this is that every message goes to all of the handlers. Does anyone know of a way to send a message to a single handler with a Logger instance?

I have a work around but I'm not exactly excited about it, I feel like I'm missing something basic here, but my google-fu is weak today I guess.

```
import logging
from contextlib import suppress 
log_fmt = logging.Formatter(
        fmt='%(levelname)s: %(asctime)s - %(name)s - : %(message)s',
        datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
    )


v = logging.FileHandler(f'log1.log')
v.setFormatter(log_fmt)
v.setLevel(logging.INFO)
v.name = f'log1'
lg = logging.getLogger('log1')
lg.setLevel(logging.INFO)
lg.addHandler(v)



b = logging.FileHandler(f'log2.log')
b.setFormatter(log_fmt)
b.setLevel(logging.INFO)
b.name = f'log2'
# I can write to different files if i create different loggers, but then we run into the flask limitation
#lg2 = logging.getLogger('log2')
#lg2.setLevel(logging.INFO)
lg.addHandler(b)

l1 = logging.getLogger('log1')

#probably there is a better way to handle this but its just an example
def to_handler(msg, name='log1'):
    msg = logging.LogRecord(name, logging.INFO, '',0,msg,[],'')
    with suppress(IndexError):
        [x for x in l1.handlers if getattr(x,'name', '') == name][0].emit(msg)

l1.to_handler = to_handler


# in a client module
import logging 
l1 = logging.getLogger('log1')
l1.to_handler('some mildly important information')
```

when setting up the logger in flask I have to do

```
app.logger = l1
```

thats why I'm not sure how I can use multiple loggers